# What do I need to include in VC2010 to be able to successfully compile an OpenGL project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 express. What is the bare minimum of headers and libs that I need to include in a OpenGL project for it to be able to compile without any errors. And I talk about the minimum, without any additional libs like GLUT or GLFW or GLEW etc.

I thought that all I need to do is to add opengl32.lib in additional dependencies, but it looks like it's not working, because VC can't recognize some of the openGL syntax like "glGenBuffers()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function prototypes declared inside `<GL/GL.h>` on windows systems are only for OpenGL versions up to 1.1 (which is about 20 years old now). Every function for extensions or versions higher than that, like `glGenBuffers` (which came with 1.5), has to be loaded dynamically using `wglGetProcAddress` to retrieve a pointer to the function (if the version/extension is supported by your hardware and driver, of course).

As this can be tedious work, there are libraries for automatic extension management, like GLEW, which do all this for you and present you with the needed function pointers in corresponding variables, so that you can directly use `glGenBuffers` and the like as ordinary functions, but they are not declared anywhere in `<GL/GL.h>`.

So no, you don't need anything else than link against `opengl32.lib` to successfully compile an OpenGL project in VS2010, but you either need to manage extensions yourself whenever you need functionality higher than version 1.1 or use a third party library that does that for you, like GLEW.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i see now :) I was hoping that i can avoid that GLEW, whenever i include it i get some strange memory errors from Visual Studio :( But it looks like that i have to see what is causing that...

Comment: @IanDess That would be a good idea, since handling extensions yourself can be a pain. Well, it's not that hard or complex a task, but it really has some advantages if you just need to call `glewInit` and can use every function you like right away. And using only 1.1 functionality isn't an option nowadays. To your errors, maybe you just forgot to call `glewInit` after the GL context is created? In this case `glGenBuffers` and its friends don't have valid values and you get an access violation (or a similar memory error) when trying to use it.

Comment: OMG dude you saved me... Thanks a lot! I've just started with openGL few days ago, so i am pretty lost in the sea of all the libraries and whatnot, so overlooking such simple thing like glewInit happens a lot :( Yep, that was the issue! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`glGenBuffer` is avalaible since OpenGL 1.5. Windows implementation is 1.1.
So basically you need GLEW :).

But for OpenGL 1.1, you just need to link against `opengl32.lib` as you did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i see now :) I was hoping that i can avoid that GLEW, whenever i include it i get some strange memory errors from Visual Studio :( But it looks like that i have to see what is causing that...